# Command to find Active Drive

Tags: vbscript, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to build a VBScript to automatically run some .exe files. The problem is that the script and the .exe files are on a flashdrive, so it needs to find the current drive letter by itself. I can do it on a batch file using `%~d0`, but I like some of the functions of VBScript better, especially the ability to send keystrokes. Anyways, I found a whole list of VBScript commands, but I am no expert and I need help with the syntax. So far I have it set to open the task manager and press some keys to have it select the "performance tab" of the task manager:

```
Dim Act :Set Act = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Act.Run("taskmgr.exe")
Success = Act.AppActivate("taskmgr")
Wscript.Sleep 250
Act.SendKeys "{TAB 5}" :WScript.Sleep 500
Act.SendKeys "{RIGHT 3}" :WScript.Sleep 500
```

I'd like to know what command I need to use to tell the script to use the drive letter where the script was executed from (USB drive).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [.ScriptFullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc5ywscw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property to get the full file spec of the running script and apply [.GetParentFolderName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22dyy47c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for the folder's path or [.GetDriveName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48e3yfdw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for just the drive letter.

```
>> Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> s = WScript.ScriptFullName
>> WScript.Echo oFS.GetParentFolderName(s), oFS.GetDriveName(s)
>>
M:\bin M:
```

cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250465/603855)